# How to copy from one minio server to another?

Tags: java, minio

I am using Minio's JAVA SDK. I managed to copy objects within the same Minio Server. Is there a way to copy the objects from one Minio server to another?

I have tried using the below code:

```
InputStream inputStream = minioClientServer1.getObject(getBucket(), fileName);
minioClientServer2.putObject(getBucket(), fileName, inputStream, (long) inputStream.available(), null, null, contentType);
```

That is I got the object from one server and then uploaded to the next. The problem that I'm facing is that the **contentType** is unknown.

Is there a way to do this without hard coding the content type?
Or downloading the object to a file then uploading is a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this applies to you because you don't provide enough information for me to be sure we're talking about the same SDK.  But from what you show, you should be able to call `statObject` in the same way that you call `getObject` and get an `ObjectStat` instance rather than an `InputStream` instance for a particular S3 object.  Once you have an `ObjectStat` instance, you should be able to call the `contentType` method on it to get the content type of the S3 object.

This should work to do what you're asking:

```
ObjectStat objectStat = minioClientServer1.statObject(getBucket(), fileName);
InputStream inputStream = minioClientServer1.getObject(getBucket(), fileName);
minioClientServer2.putObject(getBucket(), fileName, inputStream, (long) inputStream.available(), null, null, objectStat.contentType());
```

Comment: I got a ProtocolException: expected 0 bytes required 8192 bytes when I use putObject.

Comment: @MohendraAmatya - print out the `objectStat.contentType()` value or stop in your debugger and see what it is.  The value is either the correct type for the object or it isn't.  It shouldn't matter if the type came from the new call or if you hard-coded it.  If it's the same string, it should have the same effect.  So the question is what you're getting as a type value from the metadata.- Are you saying that the same copy works if you hard-code type type?  If not then this sounds like a different issue maybe.

Comment: I got the content type but when I use putObject to upload the inputStream, I get ProtocolException. Is there a way to resolve this?